# Displaying photos in carousel slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, instagram

I am trying to display some instagram photos in a jquery carousel and for some reason the pictures are displaying in reverse order and all of the photos are not displayed in the carousel slider.

The JavaScript i am using is as follows:

```
function(data) {
    for (i=0; i<20; i++){
        $("#carousel").prepend("<li><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src '" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url + "'></img></a>");
    } 
}
```

The HTML:

```
<ul id ="carousel" class="elasticslide-list">
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepend will reverse something.

Think about a prepend b prepend c, etc:

```
a -> ba -> cba -> dcba -> ...
```

Use `append` instead.

As for missing images, my guess is that there are more than the hard coded twenty.

Try:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; ++i)
```

Also, the `i` should be declared somewhere.  Hopefully it's declared at a higher scope and isn't an implicit global.

It would be a bit overkill, but if you wanted, you could also use jQuery's `each`:

```
$.each(data.data, function() {
    //"this" is now each of the data.data entries.
    //like this.images or this.link
});
```

---

Edit: It also looks like you're missing an = for your `src` attribute on the `img` tag.

I also might be tempted to set the `src` with DOM manipulation since it's possible that it won't be escaped properly if you have a quote inside of the file name (which probably won't happen).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I used the append instead and solved the reverse problem. The photos still are not displaying properly. I see in my console that i am getting the photos from instagram, but only one photo is showing when I use this code: $("$carousel li").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url + "'></img></a>");

Comment: I think it is taking the entire loop and making it one object in the <li></li>. Would the .each function solve that problem?

Comment: @user1933111 I'm not familiar with the different JS libraries that you're using, but I think that you need to create an `li` for each of the images.  That seems to be what your original code is doing though.  What is the structure of the `data`? Does it have more than one image inside of each `data.data`? If so, you'll need to repeat thumbnails or something.  Once again, not sure how the APIs/libraries work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach (see [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/quyima/1/edit?html,js,output) example), using  [layerJS](http://layerjs.org) and [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), I used images from flicker because this doesn’t need an api key.

Gesture movements work as well and you can have different types of transitions between them.

Basically you add a **stage** div put a layer and add as many **frames** as you want between for the images.

The HTML would look something like this:

```
<div data-lj-type="stage">
    <div data-lj-type="layer" data-lj-default-frame="image1">
        <div data-lj-type="frame" data-lj-name="image1" data-lj-neighbors.b="image2" class="frame">
            <image src="img/1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-lj-type="frame" data-lj-name="image2" data-lj-neighbors.b="image3" class="frame">
            <image src="img/2.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this can help you and others in the future.

disclaimer: I work on the layerJS open source library that I used here.